# If a cell is blank and if a cell in the same row's text equals something, then sum another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet, but I cannot get my head around how this works, and it's probably because I am using ranges. My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
[      A     ] [  B  ] [    C    ] [      D      ]
[Product name] [Price] [Bought by] [Has been paid]
[  PRODUCT 1 ] [ 100 ] [  Peter  ] [             ]
[  PRODUCT 2 ] [ 100 ] [  Peter  ] [      X      ]
[  PRODUCT 3 ] [ 100 ] [  Jane   ] [      X      ]
[  PRODUCT 4 ] [ 100 ] [  Jane   ] [      X      ]
[  PRODUCT 5 ] [ 100 ] [  Peter  ] [             ]
```

If D is blank and C equals a text string, add B to the sum and output it into a cell.

Here is what I have:

```
=SUM(IF(AND(ISBLANK(D2:D999), (C2:C999 = "Peter")), B2:B999, 0))
```

What I assume this would do, is:

```
if cell D2 is blank AND cell C2 equals Peter, add B2 to the sum, otherwise add 0
repeat for all rows
```

So in the above example, because Peter has not been paid for PRODUCT 1 or PRODUCT 5 (as marked with an X), it should sum the 2 prices from the Price column, which would return 200.

I feel like I'm really close, but I am really unsure. I've written a better example here, so maybe that can help:

```
sum = 0

foreach( row in rows )
    if( row.D = "" AND row.C = "Peter" )
        sum += row.Price

//insert(row, col, sum)
```

I need two of these functions. One for Jane and one for Peter. That's why I added the condition to check if the same column's cell equals "Peter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($D$2:$D$999)=0)*($C$2:$C$999 = E2)*$B$2:$B$999)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! Makes sense once I looked it up

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMIFS for this:

```
=SUMIFS($B$3:$B$7,$C$3:$C$7,"<>""",$D$3:$D$7,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need two of these functions. One for Peter and one for Jane. Jane's function should return 0 (because she has been paid) but Peter's should say 200

Comment: You can create two and edit the third parameter to `"Peter"` or `"Jane"` as needed.